# generate redshift ddls for multiple s3 text objects

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-redshift, ddl

I have many S3 objects that are all text files with the same delimiter (`|`) and retain unique headers on only the first line.

I want to create a Redshift Table DDL for each file with all fields defined as `varchar` or simply just some text-only data type format. There's a lot of material I've found relating to this use-case but haven't located something that readily accomplishes this seemingly trivial task.

The only source I've found that's somewhat does this is from [here](https://github.com/mikethoun/redshift-auto-schema). Before I just make my own tool, I wanted to check in and ask here to insure I haven't missed anything that will make this labor-intensive, monotonous task quick and easy.

Comment: You probably want to use AWS Glue to crawl your files, S3 to host them, and Spectrum to allow Redshift to read the files from S3. Once all set up correctly it's all very powerful, but there's no first class support for what you want baked into Redshift.

Comment: @MatBailie - that makes sense and totally agree. Completely forgot the use of Glue so that’s a great answer for my use-case. Thank you.